# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, pro-tem-moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: CRSouser]
[image: Jan Murphy]
[image: PolyGeo]
[image: Harry Vervet]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

> #### **Update**
>
> Please join me in welcoming Harry Vervet as our 4th moderator to the team!

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It's a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to have Cole with me.

Comment: @Luke, likewise glad to have you along.

Comment: Fantastic! Luke & ColeValleyGirl - Let's get this party started!

Comment: Congrats you two! :)

Comment: I am so excited to have mods.

Comment: A good choice!!

Comment: Great to have @CanadianGirlScout on board!

Comment: Without casting any negative aspersions on the abilities of the three (well-qualified) people, does the recent level of (in)activity justify additional moderators?

Comment: @Fortiter It's not so much "additional moderators" as it is that before was "not enough moderators". Even for slow sites, we prefer to have at least 3 persons working - this not only allows for a light workload on all persons, but also gives extra perspectives amongst the moderators.

Comment: For anyone who has not visited the G&FH Chat Rooms ([Roots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) and [Genealogy weekly chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat)) lately, those are great places to "meet" @JanMurphy.

Comment: Congratulations, @JanMurphy -- I know you'll do a great job.

Comment: Re: @Fortiter's comment on the number of moderators -- as a practical matter, I can see where it is useful to have a moderation team whose members are in different time zones, too.

Comment: Congrats @CRSouser !

Comment: Many thanks for stepping up @CRSouser and thanks should also go to the others that put their hand up.

Comment: Good luck, @CRSouser!

Comment: Hey @CRSouser - We dedicated participants at G&FH appreciate your stepping forward and help to keep the site moving towards greatness (i.e. graduation). StackExchange is a wonderful Q&A forum that genealogists really can use, and it's only a matter of time before the rest of the genealogy world discovers our nest. Your participation here will help keep you warm on some of those cold nights in Alaska.

Comment: It's great to be able to welcome @HarryVervet to the moderator team.

Comment: Congratulations, @HarryVervet -- good to have an extra pair of hands on the tiller.

Comment: Congrats @HarryVervet and welcome aboard!